# How can I split values returned by sql query into multiple columns in SQL SERVER?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a function that returns the following information when called:

```
select * from functionName(null, '1 jan 2016', '30 dec 2016')
```

output:

```
    pcode       PayoutDate

   100         2016-02-28 00:00:00:000
   100         2016-05-31 00:00:00:000
   100         3016-08-31 00:00:00:000
   100         3016-11-30 00:00:00:000
   103         2016-02-28 00:00:00:000
   103         2016-05-31 00:00:00:000
   103         3016-08-31 00:00:00:000
   103         3016-11-30 00:00:00:000
```

We do payouts to our clients at the end of February, May, August and November.

So what I want to achieve is to have each month have its own date as shown below:

```
pcode    May                        August                November

100    2016-05-31 00:00:00:000  3016-08-31 00:00:00:000  3016-11-30 00:00:00:000 
103    2016-05-31 00:00:00:000  3016-08-31 00:00:00:000  3016-11-30 00:00:00:000
```

How can I split the data set to reflect as shown above?

I don't really know how can this be tackled, Anyone with any idea?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `PIVOT`

```
SELECT * FROM 
(SELECT pcode, datename(month, PayoutDate) AS Month, PayoutDate FROM yourtable) a
PIVOT
(MIN(PayoutDate) FOR Month IN ([May], [August], [November]))b
```

Output

```
pcode May                  August               November
100   2016-05-31T00:00:00Z 3016-08-31T00:00:00Z 3016-11-30T00:00:00Z
103   2016-05-31T00:00:00Z 3016-08-31T00:00:00Z 3016-11-30T00:00:00Z
```

SQL Fiddle: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/9ed49/11/0

Answer (score 1):

Can  enter  the  function  result  into  temporary  table  . 
Here  example  table name : SOF_Pcode

```
select distinct  pcode , (select P1.PayoutDate from SOF_Pcode P1  where  P1.pcode =P.pcode and DATEPART(month,P1.PayoutDate) =5)   As  May 
, (select P1.PayoutDate from SOF_Pcode P1  where  P1.pcode =P.pcode and DATEPART(month,P1.PayoutDate) =8) As August
   , (select P1.PayoutDate from SOF_Pcode P1  where  P1.pcode =P.pcode and DATEPART(month,P1.PayoutDate) =11) As November from SOF_Pcode P
```